# Page Refreshes on Route Change and Contexts get Updates

Tags: reactjs, react-router, webhooks, react-context, page-refresh

When I click the sidebar button,(change the route), Page get Refreshed and useContext useEffect is called again. I have tried every possible variation of routing but the problem persisits.

This my App.js File

```
//App.js

  const { mode } = React.useContext(ThemeContext)

  if (window.location.pathname === ('/register')) {
    return <Register />
  }
  else if (window.location.pathname === "/") {
    return <Auth>
      <State>
        <Login />
      </State>
    </Auth>
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Auth>
        **<State>**
          <Router>

            <div className={`loaded ${mode ? "dark-layout" : "light-layout"}`}>
              <NavBar />
              <SideBar />
              <Routes>
                <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
                <Route path="/optionChain" element={<OptionChain />} />
                <Route path="/settings" element={<Settings />} />
              </Routes>

              <div className="app-content content ">
                <div className="content-wrapper container-xxl p-0">
                  <div className="content-body">
                    <Footer />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Router>
        **</State>**
      </Auth>
    </React.Fragment >
  );
```

This is the rendering happening in index.js

```
//Index.js
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Theme>
      <App />
    </Theme>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

And here in the SideBar All Links are defined.
Extra Info: navClicked2 is used to change the color of clicked sideNav item.
It is also using e.preventDefault()

```
//    SideBar Links
<li className={`nav-item ${navClicked2 ? 'active' : ''}`}>
      <Link className="d-flex align-items-center" to="/optionChain" onClick={hoverbtn2}>
       // {styling the side button here}
      </Link>
    </li>
```

The problem I am facing is that the Page is Refreshed when I change the route and the StateContext also gets refreshed.
I used useRoutes so that my Login.js and Register components are inside the Routes and place BrowserRouter in index.js

```
return useRoutes([
    {
      path: '',
      children: [
        { path: '', element: <Login /> },
        { path: 'register', element: <Register /> }
      ],
    },

    {
      path: '',
      element: (
        <MainLayout />
      ),
      children: [
        { path: 'dashboard', element: <Dashboard /> },
        { path: 'strategy', element: <Strategy /> },
        { path: 'settings', element: <Settings /> },
      ],
    },
```

**This solved the problem of Page Refresh also and Context Refresh also. But when I manually refresh the page from Chrome Refresh button, and then change the routes. Again it starts to behave as before, it starts to refresh the page on every Route Change. I Dont know why it is happening**

In the State Context I have a WebSocket

```
const [client, setClient] = React.useState(new w3cwebsocket(`ws://${}/${operator && operator.username}/${operator && operator.password}`))


React.useEffect(() => {
    try {
        client.onopen = () => {
            console.log("WebSocket Client Connected");
        };
        client.onmessage = (message) => {
            const data = JSON.parse(message.data);
            console.log(data)
            data.nifty_data &&
                setData(
                    data.nifty_data,
                    setNiftyData,
                    setNiftyExpiry,
                    niftyData
                );
            data.bnf_data &&
                setData(
                    data.bnf_data,
                    setBankNiftyData,
                    setBankNiftyExpiry,
                    bankNiftyData
                );
            if (data.index_data) {
                setIndexData(data.index_data);
                setNiftyStrike(data.index_data.NIFTY[0][4]);
                setBankNiftyStrike(data.index_data.BANKNIFTY[0][4]);
            }
        };

        client.onerror = (message) => {
            console.log("Error " + message);
        };
        client.onclose = (message) => {
            console.log("Close " + message);
        };
    } catch (e) { console.log(e) }
}, []);


return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={{ niftyData, bankNiftyData, bankNiftyData, indexData, bankNiftyExpiry, niftyExpiry, bankNiftyStrike, niftyStrike }}>
        {props.children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
)
```

I am not able to understand why after reloading the page manually, why changing the routes from the sidebar starts to refresh the page again.

Please also tell me a way where Login and Register can be in the same Router and Navbar and Sidebar do not get rendered, but when Dashboard and other routes are rendered, Sidebar and Navbar should be rendered.

> EDIT

The page is refreshing as if I clicked a href and page reloads. I am not able to understand why it is reloading because every redirect is in the `<Link to="anyLocation">...</Link>` tag.
The State Context has wrapped the Router Component in App.js

Comment: Can you more clearly explain what "refresh the page" means *exactly* in this case? Like it's just rerendering? Remounting? Something else? What exactly is the issue? Which context is having an issue? Where is `StateContext` provider component used? Can you edit the post to include a more complete and cohesive [mcve] so we've better context?

Comment: The Page reloads. The useEffect of State Context is called. The StateContext has wrapped the Router in App.js.
I tried everything, got the problem solved also by useRoutes instead of Router, but if I manually reload the page from the browser and then change the routes, then again the problem persist and on every route change, page reloads.

Comment: Are you saying the browser is reloading the *entire* app when you manually reload the page, i.e. webapp? This is completely expected behavior. Is it possible you are using `react@18` and rendering the app into a `React.StrictMode` component and seeing the effects of [Ensuring Reusable State](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state), i.e. the app/component is mounted twice as a way to help you detect unexpected side-effects and ensure reusable state?

Comment: You are right that it is expected behavior that manually reloading the webapp reloads the entire page. But once the page reloading is finished it should work normal. But when I click the route now, the route changes and the page reloads automatically too. Contexts are set to initial states, its like a manual reload. This issue with routes arives after a manual reload, before that it is working perfect

Comment: There's nothing in the code I can see that would cause a page reload. Try simplifying your code down to a more minimal example to see if you can isolate what is triggering the issue. If you can, please try to create a ***minimal**, running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live.

Answer (score 0):

remove `window.location.pathname` checks and use Protected routes instead.